# How to alert if addClass is successful?

Tags: jquery, html, css, callback, addclass

How can I make an alert with the message "it worked" if an addClass() was sucessful? This is what the addClass() code looks like:

```
$( "li.selected" ).children("ul").addClass( "childUL" );
```

The reason for this is to add a class of "childUL" for every ul on lower levels of an li.selected, it coul'd look like this for example or totally different.:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="selected">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <ul>
              <li>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/4EbLu/27/ Zlatan Ibrahimovic isn't colored green. Maybe this will clearify my question.

Cheers / Robin.

Comment: So.. `addClass()` can never fail. I think what you're probably looking for is determining whether `$( "li.selected" ).children("ul")` selected anything, in which case you can check the `.length` property.

Comment: It's always successful, why would it fail ?

Comment: What does successful mean? Does it mean it actually added a class to an element?

Comment: If there is no ul tag child it cannot add a class, isnt that a fail?

Comment: @RascalCapac so check for length

Comment: @RascalCapac I don't think about it that way. To me, the failure was in selecting the `ul`.

Comment: I have to make a loop that goes down the list tree to add the class to all child ul

Comment: @RascalCapac why that? I don't get your logic behind it. I mean, why a loop?

Comment: I want to loop this:
$( "li.selected" ).children("ul").addClass( "childUL" );
$( ".childUL" ).children("li").addClass( "childLI" );

Comment: `$( "li.selected" ).children("ul").addClass( "childUL" ).find('li').addClass( "childLI" );` ???

Comment: In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/4EbLu/27/ Zlatan Ibrahimovic isn't colored green. Maybe this will clearify my question.

Comment: So now you changed the question. It is not green because your CSS does nto allow it to be green. If all children links are supposed to be green, why not make the rule say that? .selected a { color: green; }

Comment: ok... I made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235372/count-ul-tags-that-are-children

Answer (score 2):

You can use hasClass after adding class

```
if($( "li.selected" ).children("ul").hasClass( "childUL" ))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer relies on what you mean by successful.

If the answer is the code executed so it is successful, than adding an alert right after it would be valid.

If you want to know if a class was added, you would need to check the length of the set that was returned. This assumes the class is not already there.

```
var elems = $( "li.selected" ).children("ul").addClass( "childUL" );
if ( elems.length ) {
    alert('it worked');
}
```

If you only want to know newly added classes, use not to filter out uls that already have the class.

```
var elems = $( "li.selected" ).children("ul").not(".childUL").addClass( "childUL" );
```

Comment: +1 already done but you will deserve an other one for the `.not()` logic. Looks like exaactly what OP is looking for

Answer (score 1):

`addClass` will always be *successful*. What you want to know is if there is actually some element in you stack. You can check the length :

```
 var $ul = $( "li.selected" ).children("ul");
 if($ul.length)
     $ul.addClass('childUl');
 else alert('No UL');
```